# Long/Lat information is not saved in "category" dim, unable to extract specific data

Tags: r, netcdf

i am trying to extract sea surface temperature (sst) from a netcdf4 file, , in all scipts i found the dimensions are saved in "dim", while in this particular dataset long/lat and date are saved in "var". I would like to know how i can extract for this structure the SST (variable name: TEMP) for a specific location and time.

The discussed file: https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/en4/ 
Here the code I used, I am sorry for the format, really not used to r yet.

```
nc1<-nc_open("C:////EN.4.2.0.f.profiles.g10.197506.nc")
attributes(nc1$var)
ncatt_get(nc1,attributes(nc1$var)$names[51])
ncvar_get(nc1,attributes(nc1$var)$names[51])
nc_long <- ncvar_get(nc1, attributes(nc1$var)$names[30])
nc_lat <- ncvar_get(nc1, attributes(nc1$var)$names[29])
```

Thanks for your help. 
All the best, 
moritz

Comment: You must provide what you have tried so far. Also, take a look at this page [link](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog607/Rmd/netCDF_01.htm) for more details.

Comment: I suggest you to post your question in https://gis.stackexchange.com/